# Contact Form error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, contact-form

I'm trying to make a Contact form in Laravel 
when i submit the message i got this error
i'm mostly new to laravel so i don't know why it's appearing

> Routes.php

```
    Route::post('/contact/sendmail', [
   'uses'   => 'ContactMessageController@postSendMessage',
   'as'     => 'contact.send'
]);
```

> ContactMessageController.php

```
    class ContactMessageController extends Controller
{

    public function postSendMessage(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'subject' => 'required|max:140',
            'message' => 'required|min:10'
        ]);
        $message = new ContactMessage();
        $message->email = $request['email'];
        $message->sender = $request['name'];
        $message->subject = $request['subject'];
        $message->body = $request['message'];
        $message->save();
        return redirect()->route('contact')->with(['success' => 'Message Succesfully sent']);
    }
}
```

and

> contact.blade.php

```
    @extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Contact
@endsection

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::secure('src/css/form.css') }}" />
@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('includes.info-box')
    <form action="{{ route('contact.send') }}" mathod="post" id="contact-form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="{{ Request::old('email') }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="{{ Request::old('subject') }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="message">Your Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10">{{ Request::old('message') }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit Message</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token" />
    </form>
@endsection
```

I cant find why i got this error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

Comment: you have a  spell error in mathod="post" it should be method="post"

Comment: oops that's it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo. You need to change `mathod="post"` to `method="post"`.